# Inconsistency between simulation and the probability of a "stock" hitting take profit before stop loss

Tags: programming, time-series, probability, simulations

Let's assume a stock at time $t$ is worth $X(t)$. If the returns of $X(t)$ are i.i.d. and normally distributed,the probability of $X(t)$ hitting a value $H>X(t)$ before $L<X(t)$ is $\frac{H-X(t)}{H-L}$ (not considering exchange fees and the cost of shorting).

Now, I ran a python simulation on a stochastic process with normal i.i.d returns (price diffs) and obtained results that seem inconsistent with my assumptions about the probabilities mentioned above. I took the folling steps in the simulation:

1. obtain a simulated time series of prices using the "fake_stock" function.
2. upsample the price data to 5 minute bars.
3. obtain the high, low, and close of each 5 minute bar.
4. calculate the close to high percentage (ch) of each 5 minute bar. $ch = \frac{high-close}{high-low}, 0 <=ch <= 1 $. In theory, $ch$ denotes the probability of $X(t)$ hitting the high after the low, correct? This is where the inconsistency lies.
5. run 'high_after_low' to see if $H$ was hit after $L$.
6. based on step five, I obtain a dataframe of close_to_highs and a boolean showing if they hit their respective highs before lows.

```
def fake_stock():
    '''returns a time series of prices based on gaussian returns'''
    dti = pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01 17:00", end="2019-01-01 16:00", freq="S")
    returns = np.random.normal(0, 1, len(dti))
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dti, columns=["price"])
    df["price"] = returns
    df = df.between_time("17:00", "16:00")
    df["price"] = df["price"].cumsum()
    df["price"] = df["price"] - df["price"].min()
    return df

def upsample(df, freq="5T"):
    '''upsample second bars to minutes. obtain close, high, and low of each bar'''
    upsampled_df = pd.DataFrame()
    upsampled_df.loc[:, "high"] = df["price"].resample(freq, label="left", closed="left").max()
    upsampled_df.loc[:, "low"] = df["price"].resample(freq, label="left", closed="left").min()
    upsampled_df.loc[:, "close"] = df["price"].resample(freq, label="left", closed="left").last()
    upsampled_df.loc[:, "close_to_high"] = (upsampled_df["high"]-upsampled_df["close"])/(upsampled_df["high"]-upsampled_df["low])
    return upsampled

def high_after_low_apply(row, minute_df):
    '''returns True if high was reached after low, False otherwise'''
    minute_df_after = minute_df.loc[row.end_idx:]
    first_highs = (minute_df_after.ge(row.high))
    first_lows = (minute_df_after.le(row.low))
    if ((len(first_highs) == 0) & (len(first_lows) == 0)):
        return None
    elif (len(first_highs) == 0):
        return True
    elif (len(first_lows) == 0):
        return False
    return first_highs.idxmax() > first_lows.idxmax()
```

Now, we are ready to run the simulation.

```
df = fake_stock()
upsampled_df = upsample(df)
upsampled_df.loc[:,"end_idx"]=upsampled_df.index+pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)
upsampled_df.loc[:,"high_after_low"] = upsampled_df.apply(high_after_low_apply, axis=1, args=(df,))
upsampled_df = pd.sort_values(upsampled_df, by="close_to_high")
```

Now we have the upsampled_df dataframe sorted by close_to_high values. Let's drop close_to_high values that are 0 or 1.

```
upsampled_df = upsampled_df.loc[(upsampled_df["high_after_low"]!=0)&(upsampled_df["high_after_low"]!=1)]
```

Now, I can calculate the historic probabilities of hitting high after low using a rolling window.

```
probs = (upsampled_df["close_to_high"]*upsampled_df["high_after_low]).rolling(1000).sum()/upsampled_df["close_to_high"].rolling(1000).sum()
```

when I compare probs to the average values of high_after_low, I get inconsistent results. Namely, for small close_to_high values the probability of hitting the high after the low is larger than theory suggests and vice versa.

[image]

What is the explanation for this inconsistency?

Comment: Are you sure your `(H-X(t))/(H-L)` assumption is correct? It would work by symmetry if X(t) were the average of H and L, but I don't see it working otherwise. At the very least, you'd need to apply the normal's pdf? Did you mean uniformly distributed?

Comment: What is your sample size ?

Comment: @barrycarter it's based on the assumption that E.V. for X(t) hitting any of the targets is zero. $EV(.) = (H-X(t))p + (X(t)-L)(1-p)$

Comment: @HamishGibson 30,000,000 seconds. Since i'm using simulated data in this example, sample size is not a practical constraint.

Comment: Can you please clarify why the probability of $X$ reaching $H$ before it reaches $L$ is $(H-X)/(H-L)$?

Comment: @Kermittfrog I'm assuming that the expected value of betting it would hit $H$ before $L$ is 0 which intuitively means that you cannot make money betting on the outcome of a gaussian coin flip. $EV(.) = (X-L)p + (X-H)(1-p)$. if EV=0, $p(X-L-X+H) +X - H = 0$ -> $p=\frac{H-X}{H-L}$

Comment: Is that justifiable? Shouldn't you operate on the hitting time distribution of a (geometric) Brownian motion instead?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Why do you think there should be a non-zero EV in that bet? What would those probabilities look like then?